# Get the text of a stored procedure after rename in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I encountered a strange problem today.... I did an sp_helptext on a stored procedure but the stored procedure name in the CREATE PROCEDURE statement (in the result) did not correspond to the name I used in the sp_helptext statement (see screenshot below). I tried selecting from the sys.all_sql_modules and also OBJECT_DEFINITION but it gave the same result.

In my example below I used InvIRCode_GetByInvIRID but the result gave me InvIRCode_Get**List**ByInvIRID

I did a bit of research and it seems it is a known SQL Server bug and happens when a stored procedure was renamed.

My question is this: How can I get the correct source code for a stored procedure?

The interesting thing is that when I right-click on the sp in the Object Explorer of SQL Server Management Studio and select to script the procedure to a new window, it does give the correct code.

[image: SP Code]

Comment: stop searching for miracles. It is a known issue and given the length of time that has passed since first discovered, it is unlikely to be changed any time soon. You either adjust your code to compensate or you store your database schema/ddl in source control (which you should be doing).

Answer (score 0):

Note this warning message is returned by `sp_rename`:

```
Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.
```

The text in the catalog views is not changed by `sp_rename`. The proc name will be corrected when you script the proc via SSMS or SMO. You can alter (or drop/create) modules using that script to fix the text in the catalog views after a rename.